# Mathematical name for the coefficient inside a sine function

Tags: trigonometry, terminology

Considering the following equation:
$$y = \sin(a \cdot (x + x_0)) + y_0$$
is there a mathematical name for the coefficient '$a$' ?

Comment: The *Period* is defined as $2 \pi / a$.

Comment: it controls the length of the period, and is related to frequency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coefficient $a$ is the [angular frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_frequency), i.e., the [ordinary frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency) multiplied by $2\pi$. The term $a{x_0}$ is the [phase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_(waves)) and the coefficient of $\sin(x)$, which in this case is $1$, would be the [amplitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude). As far as I know, the constant $y_0$ does not have a name.

Comment: NB: To avoid ambiguity and confusion between the two types of frequency, it would be more common to define $a$ algebraically and refer to it by the constant's letter instead of by a particular word.

Comment: At least in high school, $y_0$ (or $y=y_0$ to be pedantic) is called the *midline*.